# Not able to get eclipse paho working with ssl

Tags: c++, cmake, paho

I need some help with enabling SSL in eclipse paho.
To download and build paho I am using "ExternalProject_Add" :

```
externalproject_add(
paho
DEPENDS libressl
DOWNLOAD_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/externals/paho
GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c.git"
GIT_TAG "83cc318c96d508dd2ef26e87da23a858ff073b56"
UPDATE_COMMAND ""
PATCH_COMMAND ""
CMAKE_ARGS -DPAHO_WITH_SSL=TRUE -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DOPENSSL_INC_SEARCH_PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include -DOPENSSL_LIB_SEARCH_PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
```

As you can see I set the "CMAKE_ARGS" for using SSL. 
So far everythink works totally fine.

I have written a small program to verify that SSL is included in my paho version. The Code of thiss programm looks like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <MQTTClient.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   MQTTClient_nameValue* test=MQTTClient_getVersionInfo();
   for (int i=0;i<8;i++)if (test[i].name!=0)printf("test2: %i %s\n",i,test[i].name);
   return 0;
}
```

What it does is that it puts out some version information.

```
test2: 0 Product name
test2: 1 Version
test2: 2 Build level
```

At position 3 should be some SSL output if everything works fine, but like you see it isn't.

The CMake commands for this little program are like this:

```
add_executable(test_pahoSSL testPahoSSL.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_pahoSSL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libpaho-qtt3as.so ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so)
```

From this site https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c i got the information that i need to link xxx3as.so & xxx3cs.so which should be the libs which include SSL support.

When I hard-code a

```
#define OPENSSL 1
```

in the "MQTTCLinet.h" my test-program gives the extended output (with SLL).

From the build and linking process everything seems to work fine, but i don't get any SSL information output. Can someone point out the mistake(s) I am doing ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to **maually** build paho instead of using `ExternalProject()`? Then, try to remove source directory with paho (which is generated by `ExternalProject()`), and rerun `cmake` - there are could be cache-related issues.